# Ubuntu TV voice commands?

Tags: ubuntu-tv, voice-recognition

I've skimmed google, and the only information I could find was, Ubuntu has voice command capabilities. Since Ubuntu T.V. via PPA is more or less just an interface and uses the original OS as it's foundation. Is it safe to assume that it can work via voice control?

Answer (score 0):

The KDE.org has the KMouth, a voice synth interface, available on Software Central (apt) of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trust Tahr.

There is male and female voices in many languages.

Comment: So, what you're telling me is, I assign my new ubuntu T.V. a female voice and I can tell her to fetch me youtube?

Comment: It's part of solution, isn't a voice-recognition system.

Comment: Search for "Simon" on Software Center of Ubuntu. Simon is a speech recognition program that replaces the mouse and keyboard.